# How to print only the last result of an array of sum in python

Tags: python, arrays, sum

I want to calculate the sum of the natural numbers from 1 up to an input number. I wrote this code:

```
number=int(input("enter a natural number"))
if number<0: 
    print("The number is not positive") 
else:   
   n=0   
   for i in range (1,number+1):
        n+=i
        print(n)
```

But it prints multiple numbers instead. For example, if the user puts five, the program should print 15, but I get this:

```
1
3
6
10
15
```

How can I fix the code so that only `15` appears?

Comment: Just try to move the last statement out side of ```for-loop:```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think about the problem logically. Why do you suppose that the multiple `print`s occur? Hint: how is indentation used in Python? How is the `print(n)` code indented - is it inside the loop, or outside? Therefore, will it run only once, or will it run every time through the loop? What should happen instead? Therefore, how should that line of code be indented?

Comment: (as an aside: "resolve" does not mean the same thing as "solve", and it is not useful to try to tag the question that way. Tags are supposed to be about the *tools you are using* for the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the steps because your print statement is in your for loop.
Change it like this:

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive natural number: "))
if number < 0:
    print("The number needs to be positive")
    exit()  # Stops the program

result = 0
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    result += i

print(result)    # We print after the calculations
```

There's also a mathematical alternative (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)):

```py
number = int(input("Enter a positive natural number: "))
if number < 0:
    print("The number needs to be positive")
    exit()  # Stops the program
print(number * (number + 1) / 2)
```

Comment: Excellent! It was really easy and obvius, thanks!
I did it with the mathematical alternative before, but I wanted to practice the loops

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
number = int(input("enter a natural number"))
if number < 0:
    print("The number is not positive")
else:
    n = 0
    for i in range (1,number + 1):
        n += i
    print(n)
```

Comment: That works! But I think the best solution is the one above, putting the print outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

As I've pointed out and suggested earlier in comments, you could move the print statement out of *for-loop* to print the final *sum*.

Or you could try to use *generator expression* to get all number's total (sum), because we don't care the intermediate *sums*.

This simple *sum* of all up to the *number* in one shot.

```py
number=int(input("enter a natural number"))
if number < 0: 
    print("The number is not positive") 
    # exit or try again           <---------
else:
    print(sum(range(1, number + 1)))             # given 5 -> print 15
```

Comment: Yes! That fixed everything, I did it with the sum before but I was trying to practice the loops. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is that you are printing the n every time you change it. You are looking for the last answer when you run the code. This code should solve it.

```
number = int(input("enter a natural number"))
if number < 0:
    print("The num < 0")
else:
    n = 0
    l = []
    for i in range (0, number+1):   
        n+=i
        l.append(n)
    print(l[len(l)-1])
```